# how to create a 3 dimensional circle window in spat stat?

Tags: r, 3d, spatstat, netcoreapp3.1

I am struggling to create a 3d disc window for the pp3 in spatatat.
the shape of the window is similar to a petri dish: a radius of 5cm and the wall is 3 cm high.
i managed to create a 3d box, but i cant figure how to do it for a circle.
is it possible to do?
does spatstat know how to analyze point pattern in a 3d circle?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Spatstat han only handle boxes in 3d and higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a cylinder.

Currently `spatstat` only supports rectangular box regions (in 3D and higher dimensions).

I will take this as a feature request. Do you have data that you could share with us?